# iOS how to center MKMapView on MKAnnotationView callout accessory after tap?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

How would one go about centering the mapView on a MKAnnotationView's calloutAccessory? I know how to center the map on the actual annotationView, but I'm at a loss as to how to center the map on the annotationView's calloutAccessory. Any ideas?

```
// This centers the map on the MKAnnotationView. However, I need to be able to
// center the map on the MKAnnotationView's calloutAccessory.
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = view.annotation;
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:[annotation coordinate] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `MKMapView` method `convertPoint: toCoordinateFromView:` method to convert the centre of the annotation view to a coordinate and then center the map on that coordinate -

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    CGPoint annotationCenter=CGPointMake(control.frame.origin.x+(control.frame.size.width/2),control.frame.origin.y+(control.frame.size.height/2));

    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter=[mapView convertPoint:annotationCenter toCoordinateFromView:control.superview];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:newCenter animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a legend and a boss. Thank you!! The code you posted enabled me to center the map on the actual UIControl that was tapped. In order to adapt your answer to fit my requirements I simply swapped all references to `control` to `control.superview`. Where you had `toCoordinateFromView:control.superview`, I kept that line verbatim, no translation need. With these small edits I'm now able to center the entire accessoryView on the map in response to a user tapping the accessoryView's control. Sweet!!